# Pumping lemma for Context-Free Languages

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages, pumping-lemma

I have a question about a specific pumping lemma problem for Context-Free Languages.

Suppose we have the following Language:

```
L = {(a^i)(b^j)(c^k)(d^l) | 0 < i < k AND j > l > 0 }
```

Here is my attemp to prove that the language is not context-free:

Assume L context-free. Take the constant n>0 from the lemma.

```
Let Z = (a^n)(b^n+1)(c^n+1)(d^n), Z ∈ L.
```

Than according to the lemma, Z can be written as Z = uvwxy where the following properties hold:

```
1. |vx| >= 1
2. |vwx| <= n
3. for every i >= 0, u(v^i)w(x^i)y ∈ L.
```

We have 6 different possibilities for vwx

```
1. vwx = a^i, i <= n
2. vwx = (a^i)(b^j), i+j <= n
3. vwx = b^i, i <= n
4. vwx = (b^î)(c^j), i+j <= n
5. vwx = (c^i), i <= n
6. vwx = (c^i)(d^j)), i+j <= n
```

Is this right so far ? The things that I'm unsure off, is if my different cases of vwx is right.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

So far, so good, except you missed the case where vxy consists entirely of d's from the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you. Don't know how I could miss it :)

Comment: I think I made a misstake. Shouldn't I state that i and j can't be 0 ? How can I choose the pumping length if I don't know if i or j is zero ?